# What format is this string representing serv_addr buffer?

Tags: c, networking, format, byte

So I've been reading this tutorial on how to use Frida: https://www.frida.re/docs/functions/ and I've encountered the following:

```
$ ./client 127.0.0.1
connect() is at: 0x400780

Here's the serv_addr buffer:
02 00 13 88 7f 00 00 01 30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30
Press ENTER key to Continue
```

The tutorial states that the **bytes** represent 0x1388 or 5000 so clearly its not in hex or decimal. I tried using base64 converters to convert the string to see if 0x1388 or 5000 comes up but no luck.

What format is this exactly in? I haven't done low level programming lately and if i recall, bytes are groups of 8 bits 1s and 0s.

EDIT: 
Yup, the tutorial states this represents a struct. But how did he know that it represents 0x1388? If I received a string like this is there a way for me to understand that it represents a particular value without being the author of the code that sent the message?

Comment: It's `struct sockaddr_in` according to your linked page.

Comment: The bytes `13` and `88` are in that output, so one could guess that's where the `0x1388` comes from. One could also guess that it's the raw byte-wise output from a binary structure, which could be confirmed if you looked at the code.

Comment: @EugeneSh. But what format is the struct, how did he retrieve 0x1388 from this string?

Comment: Looks like raw binary to me. 3rd and 4th  bytes are 0x13 and 0x88. The `sin_port` in `sockaddr_in` is in network order. according to docs.

Comment: Numbers appear to be in big endian format - not uncommon with network-related data.

Comment: Is this the full code here? In any case it is a sockaddr_in, for ipv4, address family, port 5000 and address 127.0.0.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant parts of the code is this:

```
printf ("\nHere's the serv_addr buffer:\n");
b = (unsigned char *) &serv_addr;
for (i = 0; i != sizeof (serv_addr); i++)
  printf ("%s%02x", (i != 0) ? " " : "", b[i]);
```

What it is doing is simply printing the raw data from the structure `serv_addr` (which is of type `struct sockaddr_in`).

There's no "string" here (in the sense of a C null-terminated byte string).

The `0x1388` is the value of `serv_addr.sin_port`, which is printed as the third and fourth byte (`13` and `88`, in network ([big endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Big-endian)) byte order).

---

Knowing that the output is the raw data of a `sockaddr_in` structure, we can decipher the data easily

- `02 00` This is the `sin_family` member, with the value `2` (decimal). This value corresponds to `AF_INET`. This is in host byte order.
- `13 88` This is (as already mentioned) the network byte order of the port in `sin_port`.
- `7f 00 00 01` This is the `sin_addr` member, and corresponds to the IP address `127.0.0.1` (`7f` is `127`). This is also in network byte order.
- The rest, `30 30 30 30 30 30 30 30`, is "garbage" that fills the structure up to a common size for `struct sockaddr`, which is 16 bytes long.

Comment: So its actually hex... but in big endian? But the hex value is 0x1388. Sorry if my question sounds stupid. I'm going to review endianness and reread your reply.